# Drupal 7's States API: Why won't this code work?

Tags: 7, javascript

Scratching my head on this.  Trying to get a few fields in a node edit form to be visible only when a select element's value is 'sponsor':

```
function iv_persona_helper_form_persona_node_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
  $lang = $form['field_persona_type']['#language'];

  $sponsored_control_states = array(
    'visible' => array(
      ':input[name="field_persona_type['. $lang .']"]' => array('value', 'sponsor'),
    ),
  );

  $form['field_sponsored_url']['#states'] = $sponsored_control_states;
  $form['field_sponsored_text']['#states'] = $sponsored_control_states;
  $form['field_sponsored_description']['#states'] = $sponsored_control_states;

  $form['#validate'][] = 'iv_persona_helper_form_persona_node_form_validate';
}
```

I know the form_alter is being invoked, but those fields visibility is not at all changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `'value' => 'sponsor'` instead of `'value', 'sponsor'`.

Comment: Thanks Charlie S.. you spotted my bug:
Try `'value' => 'sponsor'` instead of `'value', 'sponsor'`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly without seeing the form as well but I would guess your form has no field with the name of:

```
field_persona_type['. $lang .']
```

Does that definitely match the field you are trying to use.

You can look in the source code of the page and look at that form element and see what its "name" is and make your code use the same name.