# fieldset stays open regardless of checkbox

Tags: 7, javascript

I've an application that fetches data off an Oracle database. Now, I'm adding fieldsets which will be visible based on the value. However, my fieldset stays open regardless of the value. I need to do this in a loop, as I need as many fieldsets as the number of children. So I've used a variable, based on [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/82778/17632). To debug, I set #default_value to both 0 and 0 based on whether a field has a value. Fieldset stays open on both. What am I missing?

My code (I'm posing only the relevant parts)

```
for ($x=0;$x<count($child);$x++) {
    for ($y=0;$y<$form_state['num_names'];$y++) {
      $form['c'][$x][$y]['info'] =  [
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => ($lang == 'tr')?'Çocukları / Bakmakla Yükümlü Olduğu Kişilerin Durumu':'Status of Children Dependent On or Living With The Taxpayer',
        '#collapsed' => false,
        '#collapsible' => false,
        '#prefix' => '<div id="agi-fieldset-wrapper">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
        'info' => [
          '#type' => 'markup',
          '#markup' => ($lang == 'tr')?'Çocuğunuz 18 yaşından büyük ve eğitimine devam ediyorsa; eğitim durumu bilgilerini doldurunuz. Eğitimine devam etmiyor ise, Asgari Geçim İndirimi kapsamında değildir. Çocuğunuz 24 yaşından büyük ise Asgari Geçim İndirimi kapsamında değildir.':'If your other is older than 18 and continuing his/her education, fill out the education status information. If he/she is not continuing his/her education, he/she is not covered in the Minumum Living Allowance. If your other is older than 24, he/she is not covered in the Minumum Living Allowance.',
          '#prefix' => '<span class="agi-warning">',
          '#suffix' => '</span>'
        ],
      ];
      $form['c'][$x][$y]['info']['first_name'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => ($lang == 'tr')?'Ad':'Name',
        '#default_value' => ($form_state['num_names']>1)?'':$child[$x]['CHILD_FIRST_NAME'],
        '#size' => 20,
        '#maxlength' => 20,
      ];
      $form['c'][$x][$y]['info']['middle_name'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => ($lang == 'tr')?'Orta Ad':'Middle Name',
        '#default_value' => ($form_state['num_names']>1)?'':$child[$x]['CHILD_MIDDLE_NAME'],
        '#size' => 20,
        '#maxlength' => 20,
      ];
      $form['c'][$x][$y]['info']['last_name'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => ($lang == 'tr')?'Soyad':'Last Name',
        '#default_value' => $person['LASTNAME'],
        '#size' => 20,
        '#maxlength' => 20,
      ];
      $form['c'][$x][$y]['info']['tckn'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => ($lang == 'tr')?'T.C. Kimlik No':'T.C. Identity Number',
        '#default_value' => ($form_state['num_names']>1)?'':$child[$x]['TC_KIMLIK_NO'],
        '#size' => 20,
        '#maxlength' => 20,
      ];
      $form['c'][$x][$y]['info']['birth_date'] = [
        '#type' => 'date_popup',
        '#title' => ($lang == 'tr')?'Doğum Tarihi':'Date of Birth',
        '#default_value' => ($form_state['num_names']>1)?'':date('Y-m-d',strtotime($child[$x]['BIRTH_DATE'])),
        '#date_format' => 'd/m/Y',
        '#size' => 20,
        '#maxlength' => 20,
      ];
      $form['c'][$x][$y]['info']['father_name'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => ($lang == 'tr')?'Baba Adı':'Father\'s Name',
        '#default_value' => $person['CINSIYET'] == 'M'?$person['FIRSTNAME']:$other['SPOUSE_FIRST_NAME'],
        '#size' => 20,
        '#maxlength' => 20,
      ];
      $form['c'][$x][$y]['info']['mother_name'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => ($lang == 'tr')?'Anne Adı':'Mother\'s Name',
        '#default_value' => $person['CINSIYET'] == 'F'?$person['FIRSTNAME']:$other['SPOUSE_FIRST_NAME'],
        '#size' => 20,
        '#maxlength' => 20,
      ];
      $form['c'][$x][$y]['info']['gender'] = [
        '#type' => 'radios',
        '#title' => ($lang == 'tr')?'Cinsiyeti':'Gender',
        '#options' => ($lang == 'tr')?['F'=>'Kız','M'=>'Erkek']:['F' => 'Girl','M' => 'Boy'],
        '#default_value' => ($form_state['num_names']>1)?'':trim($child[$x]['GENDER']),
      ];
      $form['c'][$x][$y]['info']['x'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => ($lang == 'tr')?'Okulun Adı':'School\'s Name',
        '#default_value' => $x,
      ];
      $form['c'][$x][$y]['info']['studying'] = [
        '#type' => 'checkbox',
        '#title' => ($lang == 'tr')?'Çalışıyor mu?':'Studying?',
        //'#default_value' => (isset($child[$x]['SCHOOL_NAME']))?1:0,
        '#default_value' => 0,
      ];
      $form['c'][$x][$y]['info']['education'] = [
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => ($lang == 'tr')?'Eğitim Bilgileri':'Education Details',
        '#collapsed' => false,
        '#collapsible' => false,
        '#states' => [
          'visible' => [
            ':input[name="c[info]['.$x.'][0][studying]"]' => ['value' => 1],
          ],
        ],
      ];
      $form['c'][$x][$y]['info']['education']['education_type'] = [
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => ($lang == 'tr')?'Eğitim Tipi':'Education Type',
        '#options' => ($lang == 'tr')?['İlköğretim','Lise','Üniversite']:['Primary School'=>'İlköğretim','High School'=>'Lise','University'=>'Üniversite'],
        '#default_value' => ($form_state['num_names']>1)?'':$child[$x]['EDUCATION_TYPE'],
      ];
      $form['c'][$x][$y]['info']['education']['school_name'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => ($lang == 'tr')?'Okulun Adı':'School\'s Name',
        '#default_value' => ($form_state['num_names']>1)?'':$child[$x]['SCHOOL_NAME'],
      ];
      $form['c'][$x][$y]['info']['education']['school_startdate'] = [
        '#type' => 'date_popup',
        '#title' => ($lang == 'tr')?'Okulun Başlangıç Tarihi':'School Start Date',
        '#default_value' => ($form_state['num_names']>1)?'':date('Y-m-d',strtotime($child[$x]['SCHOOL_STARTDATE'])),
        '#date_format' => 'd/m/Y',
        '#date_year_range' => '-50:+0'
      ];
      $form['c'][$x][$y]['info']['education']['school_enddate'] = [
        '#type' => 'date_popup',
        '#title' => ($lang == 'tr')?'Okulun Bitiş Tarihi':'School End Date',
        '#default_value' => ($form_state['num_names']>1)?'':date('Y-m-d',strtotime($child[$x]['SCHOOL_STARTDATE'])),
        '#date_format' => 'd/m/Y',
        '#date_year_range' => '-50:+0'
      ];
      $form['c'][$x][$y]['info']['remove_person'] = [
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => ($lang == 'tr')?'Kişi Sil':'Remove Person',
        '#submit' => ['suweb_agi_add_more_remove_one'],
        '#attributes' => ['style' => 'float:right', 'data-id' => $x],
        '#ajax' => [
          'callback' => 'suweb_agi_add_more_callback',
          'wrapper' => 'agi-fieldset-wrapper',
        ],
      ];
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I made a typo. I had to do '`:input[name="c['.$x.'][0][info][studying]"]' => ['checked' => TRUE],` instead.